# Asking for account linking in Google Actions v2 fails "ReferenceError: SignIn is not defined"

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm migrating the code over and i can't get my account linking sign in process to work. After looking at the documentation and code i don't see any error in the way i'm calling SignIn().
I've also made sure to update action.json and add the v2 account linking stuff in there, and my app always had account linking working so the account linking section in the Console is up to date. I'm using Action SDK and not Dialogflow.

```
const {actionssdk} = require('actions-on-google');
const app = actionssdk({debug: true});
app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', conv => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn())
})

app.intent('actions.intent.SIGN_IN', (conv, input, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const access = conv.user.access.token // possibly do something with access token
     conv.ask('Great, thanks for signing in! What do you want to do next?')
    } else {
      conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next?`)
    }
})
module.exports.assistant = app;
```

Logs:

```
ReferenceError: SignIn is not defined
    at app.intent.conv (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/src/routes/google_home.js:4:16)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/actionssdk.js:138:23)
    at next (native)
    at /usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/actionssdk.js:22:71
    at __awaiter (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/actionssdk.js:18:12)
    at Function.handler (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/actionssdk.js:85:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:55:32)
    at next (native)
    at /usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:22:71
    at __awaiter (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:18:12)
    at standard (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:51:41)
    at /usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/framework/express.js:23:13
    at omni (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:44:53)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
    at next (/usr/local/lucida/web/client-apps/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include `SignIn` when you import the library:

```
const {actionssdk, SignIn} = require('actions-on-google');
```